# Stop mouse cursor from disappearing when entering watching YouTube fullscreen

Tags: google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, youtube

When I enter fullscreen on YouTube videos the mouse cursor disappears from the screen. This is very annoying as I have a multi-monitor setup...

Right clicking on the desktop a few times can usually bring the cursor back but clicking back into Chrome hides it again.

Not sure if this is due to Chrome hiding the cursor or if its code on YouTube thats asking the browser to hide the cursor...

*(Not sure if this is a web-applications question or not. Feel free to vote for this to be moved.)*